# Passing a JSON array to JS and then to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a json file like this.

```
{
    "name" : [
        "Alsa", "Alice", "Alas", "Alpha", "Beta", "Bervis", "Bankai", "Celcia", "Celsa", "Ceasar", 
        "Domino", "Dorito", "David", "Eurius", "Easter", "Ethium", "Fourin", "Flora", "Fifa", "Genius"
    ]
}
```

I would perform a jQuery AJAX call like this.

```
            function method1(){
                $.ajax({
                url: "name_suggestion.json",
                type: "GET",
                dataType : "JSON",
                success : function(data){
                    for(i in data.name){
                        name_array.push(data.name[i]);
                    }
                }
            });
            }
            function method2(){
                $.post('search_name.php', {
                      names: JSON.stringify(name_array)
                    }, function(data, status){
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                );
            }
            $.when(method1()).then(method2);
```

In PHP file,

```
<?php
$nameData = json_decode($_POST['names']);
print_r($nameData[1]);
?>
```

When the function is called, it shows an error saying array key is not defined.

If I pass a normal array written in JavaScript, it won't show the error but that's not how I want to do:)
I am just into AJAX so if there is any mistake, I would love to know!

EDIT:
Here is the final code which works(Thanks for the answer)

```
          var name_array = [];
            function method1() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "name_suggestion.json",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function(data) {
                        name_array = data.name;
                        method2(name_array); 
                    }
                });
            }

            function method2(name_array) {
                $.get('search_name.php', {
                    names: JSON.stringify(name_array)
                }, function(data, status) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
            }
            method1();
```

Comment: You can skip the `for` loop and just say `name_array = data.name;`.  JSON is, after all, Javascript notation.

Comment: If I can offer a general suggestion... consider dropping jQuery.  It isn't needed these days, as browser APIs have become quite robust and standardized.  You can use the Fetch API instead of AJAX via jQuery.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: My JSON array contain more than one entries. I have also removed the for loop and tried it. Thanks for the answers! I would also look into fetch API.

Comment: What debugging have you done to pin down the cause of the problem. Have you checked that PHP is actually getting the array you're trying to send?

Comment: The array is received but I can't actually access the data. If I tried, it would show an error.

Comment: _Side note:_ Why post the data as json? If you just do: `names: name_array,` when you post the data, you can just get it as an array in PHP with: `$nameData = $_POST['names'];`. Your `JSON.stringify()` and `json_decode()` shouldn't be necessary here at all.

Answer (score 0):

Picking up on the suggestion above by @Brad - the `Fetch` api offers an easy to use, powerful and reliable means of sending ajax requests. An "All-in-One" example solution using Fetch

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['names'] ) ){

        # In the Fetch call we set a FormData parameter called "names" which we access here.
        $data=json_decode( $_POST['names'] );
        # The data we want is within the property "name"
        $names=$data->name;
        
        # do something with the data
        foreach( $names as $index => $name )echo $name;
        
        exit();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        
            const getresponse=(r)=>r.text();
            const callback=(res)=>console.log(res)
            
            const json={
                "name" : [
                    "Alsa", "Alice", "Alas", "Alpha", "Beta", "Bervis", "Bankai", "Celcia", "Celsa", "Ceasar", 
                    "Domino", "Dorito", "David", "Eurius", "Easter", "Ethium", "Fourin", "Flora", "Fifa", "Genius"
                ]
            };
            
            let fd=new FormData();
                fd.set( 'names', JSON.stringify( json ) );// set the property we will access in PHP
                
            fetch( location.href, { method:'post', body:fd })
                .then( getresponse )
                .then( callback )
                .catch( alert ) 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will start digging into fetch API!